# undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The error occurs on this line:

```
  <p><small><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</small></p>
```

Why is it happening, and how do I solve it?

I'm sorry for the lack of code provided. Just don't know what to give you guys.

Comment: Are you sure that `comment.created_at` is not nil?

Comment: Nope. It's not nil. `=> Wed, 08 Jan 2014 15:22:13 UTC +00:00` @user2503775

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a quick browse on the code for `time_ago_in_words` and saw that it calls the method `>` in  `distance_of_time_in_words`.

It is probably returning that error since the argument you provided, `comment.created_at`, is returning `nil`. This `nil` is then being compared to another value, which is why you are getting that error. Make sure that you don't provide a `nil` arg to `time_ago_in_words` by doing a nil conditional like:

```
<% if comment.created_at %>
  <p><small><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</small></p>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Beautiful. Beautiful from all angles.

Comment: It might be a little more readable with `if comment.persisted?`